# Parsing duplicate properties in XML

Tags: python-3.x, xml, android-layout

I've got to work with an .XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<typekitSyncState>
  <state>2f1b61f7296e340f27be2925b5485719f04efcb8</state>
  <fonts type="array">
    <font>
      <url>https://someURI</url>
      <id>25367</id>
      <properties>
        <fullName>Heisei Kaku Gothic Std W3</fullName>
        <familyName>Heisei Kaku Gothic Std</familyName>
        <variationName>W3</variationName>
        <familyURL>https://typekit.com/fonts/heisei-kaku-gothic-std</familyURL>
        <familyWebId>mpll</familyWebId>
        <fvd>n3</fvd>
        <isVariable>false</isVariable>
        <i18n>
          <locales type="array">
            <locale>
              <ianaTag>ja</ianaTag>
              <fullName>平成角ゴシック Std W3</fullName>
              <familyName>平成角ゴシック Std</familyName>
            </locale>
          </locales>
        </i18n>
      </properties>
    </font>
  </fonts>
</typekitSyncState>
```

I'm interested in extracting certain properties, mainly the font names.

```
for element in root.iter():
  if element.tag == "fullName":
    print("%s - %s" % (element.tag, element.text))


fullName - Heisei Kaku Gothic Std W3
fullName - 平成角ゴシック Std W3
```

So far so good, but releases that it's added the fullName property as well as the *local* fullname property which confuses matters. I want to be able to access the English and Japanese names separately.

I'm new to .XML and finding it's idiosyncrasies somewhat confusing. I tried using beautiful soup and then Etree.

```
for child in root:
  # state, fonts (plural)
  for child2 in child:
    # font (singual)
    for child3 in child2:
      # properties
      for child4 in child3:
        # The good stuff
        # fullName, familyName, variationName,
        if isinstance(child4.tag, str):
          print(child4.tag, child4.text)

          if child4.tag == "fullName":
            print (child4.attrib)
        for child5 in child4:
          print ("5  ", child5.tag, child5.attrib)
```

`if child4.tag == "fullName"` wasn't working. I then went down a rabbit hole trying to find examples of XML parsing that matched my flavour of XML. Mine doesn't seem to have namespaces.

What I'd like is this something like:

```
for property in fonts:
  full = font.fullname
  fam  = font.familyname
  vari = font.variationname
  if (font.locale) exists:
    full_local  = font.locale.fullname
  else: full_local = ""
  print(fill, fam, vari, full_local) 

>> Heisei Kaku Gothic Std W3, Heisei Kaku Gothic Std, W3, 平成角ゴシック Std W
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


xml_doc = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<typekitSyncState>
  <state>2f1b61f7296e340f27be2925b5485719f04efcb8</state>
  <fonts type="array">
    <font>
      <url>https://someURI</url>
      <id>25367</id>
      <properties>
        <fullName>Heisei Kaku Gothic Std W3</fullName>
        <familyName>Heisei Kaku Gothic Std</familyName>
        <variationName>W3</variationName>
        <familyURL>https://typekit.com/fonts/heisei-kaku-gothic-std</familyURL>
        <familyWebId>mpll</familyWebId>
        <fvd>n3</fvd>
        <isVariable>false</isVariable>
        <i18n>
          <locales type="array">
            <locale>
              <ianaTag>ja</ianaTag>
              <fullName>平成角ゴシック Std W3</fullName>
              <familyName>平成角ゴシック Std</familyName>
            </locale>
          </locales>
        </i18n>
      </properties>
    </font>
  </fonts>
</typekitSyncState>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, 'xml')

full_name = soup.select_one('font > properties > fullName').text
family_name = soup.select_one('font > properties > familyName').text
locale_names = {l.find('ianaTag').text: l.find('fullName').text for l in soup.select(r'font locales locale')}

print(family_name)
print(full_name)
print(locale_names)
```

Prints:

```
Heisei Kaku Gothic Std
Heisei Kaku Gothic Std W3
{'ja': '平成角ゴシック Std W3'}
```